# how to add jdbc driver jar into skywalking 6.5.0 image file in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am using skywalking 6.5.0 to monitor my apps in kubernetes cluster, this is my skywalking ui yaml config:

```
{
  "kind": "Deployment",
  "apiVersion": "extensions/v1beta1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "oap",
    "namespace": "fat",
    "selfLink": "/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/fat/deployments/oap",
    "uid": "41438118-5ae4-4da2-b3d5-6e082263e360",
    "resourceVersion": "44426777",
    "generation": 52,
    "creationTimestamp": "2020-02-28T02:53:28Z",
    "labels": {
      "app": "oap",
      "release": "skywalking"
    },
    "annotations": {
      "deployment.kubernetes.io/revision": "14",
      "kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration": "{\"apiVersion\":\"apps/v1\",\"kind\":\"Deployment\",\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{},\"name\":\"oap\",\"namespace\":\"dabai-fat\"},\"spec\":{\"replicas\":1,\"selector\":{\"matchLabels\":{\"app\":\"oap\"}},\"template\":{\"metadata\":{\"labels\":{\"app\":\"oap\",\"release\":\"skywalking\"}},\"spec\":{\"containers\":[{\"env\":[{\"name\":\"JAVA_OPTS\",\"value\":\"-Xmx2g -Xms2g\"},{\"name\":\"SW_CLUSTER\",\"value\":\"standalone\"},{\"name\":\"SKYWALKING_COLLECTOR_UID\",\"valueFrom\":{\"fieldRef\":{\"fieldPath\":\"metadata.uid\"}}},{\"name\":\"SW_STORAGE\",\"value\":\"elasticsearch\"},{\"name\":\"SW_STORAGE_ES_CLUSTER_NODES\",\"value\":\"172.30.184.10:9200\"},{\"name\":\"SW_NAMESPACE\",\"value\":\"dabai-fat\"},{\"name\":\"SW_ES_USER\",\"value\":\"elastic\"},{\"name\":\"SW_ES_PASSWORD\",\"value\":\"XXXXXX\"}],\"image\":\"registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/dabai_app_k8s/dabai_fat/skywalking-oap-server:6.5.0\",\"imagePullPolicy\":\"Always\",\"livenessProbe\":{\"initialDelaySeconds\":15,\"periodSeconds\":20,\"tcpSocket\":{\"port\":12800}},\"name\":\"oap\",\"ports\":[{\"containerPort\":11800,\"name\":\"grpc\"},{\"containerPort\":12800,\"name\":\"rest\"}],\"readinessProbe\":{\"initialDelaySeconds\":15,\"periodSeconds\":20,\"tcpSocket\":{\"port\":12800}},\"resources\":{\"limits\":{\"memory\":\"2Gi\"},\"requests\":{\"memory\":\"1Gi\"}}}],\"imagePullSecrets\":[{\"name\":\"regcred\"}],\"serviceAccountName\":\"skywalking-oap-sa\"}}}}\n"
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "replicas": 1,
    "selector": {
      "matchLabels": {
        "app": "oap"
      }
    },
    "template": {
      "metadata": {
        "creationTimestamp": null,
        "labels": {
          "app": "oap",
          "release": "skywalking"
        },
        "annotations": {
          "kubectl.kubernetes.io/restartedAt": "2020-04-18T18:30:58+08:00"
        }
      },
      "spec": {
        "containers": [
          {
            "name": "oap",
            "image": "registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/dabai_app_k8s/dabai_fat/skywalking-oap-server:6.5.0",
            "ports": [
              {
                "name": "grpc",
                "containerPort": 11800,
                "protocol": "TCP"
              },
              {
                "name": "rest",
                "containerPort": 12800,
                "protocol": "TCP"
              }
            ],
            "env": [
              {
                "name": "JAVA_OPTS",
                "value": "-Xmx2g -Xms2g"
              },
              {
                "name": "SW_CLUSTER",
                "value": "standalone"
              },
              {
                "name": "SKYWALKING_COLLECTOR_UID",
                "valueFrom": {
                  "fieldRef": {
                    "apiVersion": "v1",
                    "fieldPath": "metadata.uid"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "name": "SW_STORAGE",
                "value": "mysql"
              },
              {
                "name": "SW_JDBC_URL",
                "value": "jdbc:mysql://45.131.218.134:3309/report?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&transformedBitIsBoolean=true&useSSL=false&verifyServerCertificate=false"
              },
              {
                "name": "SW_NAMESPACE",
                "value": "fat"
              },
              {
                "name": "SW_DATA_SOURCE_USER",
                "value": "root"
              },
              {
                "name": "SW_DATA_SOURCE_PASSWORD",
                "value": "uwesGwew2rewd109dskhgwugPD"
              }
            ],
            "resources": {
              "limits": {
                "memory": "2Gi"
              },
              "requests": {
                "memory": "1Gi"
              }
            },
            "livenessProbe": {
              "tcpSocket": {
                "port": 12800
              },
              "initialDelaySeconds": 15,
              "timeoutSeconds": 1,
              "periodSeconds": 20,
              "successThreshold": 1,
              "failureThreshold": 3
            },
            "readinessProbe": {
              "tcpSocket": {
                "port": 12800
              },
              "initialDelaySeconds": 15,
              "timeoutSeconds": 1,
              "periodSeconds": 20,
              "successThreshold": 1,
              "failureThreshold": 3
            },
            "terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log",
            "terminationMessagePolicy": "File",
            "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent"
          }
        ],
        "restartPolicy": "Always",
        "terminationGracePeriodSeconds": 30,
        "dnsPolicy": "ClusterFirst",
        "serviceAccountName": "skywalking-oap-sa",
        "serviceAccount": "skywalking-oap-sa",
        "securityContext": {},
        "imagePullSecrets": [
          {
            "name": "regcred"
          }
        ],
        "schedulerName": "default-scheduler"
      }
    },
    "strategy": {
      "type": "RollingUpdate",
      "rollingUpdate": {
        "maxUnavailable": "25%",
        "maxSurge": "25%"
      }
    },
    "revisionHistoryLimit": 10,
    "progressDeadlineSeconds": 600
  },
  "status": {
    "observedGeneration": 52,
    "replicas": 1,
    "updatedReplicas": 1,
    "unavailableReplicas": 1,
    "conditions": [
      {
        "type": "Progressing",
        "status": "True",
        "lastUpdateTime": "2020-08-20T13:34:42Z",
        "lastTransitionTime": "2020-04-02T03:01:31Z",
        "reason": "NewReplicaSetAvailable",
        "message": "ReplicaSet \"oap-7cffc4c77d\" has successfully progressed."
      },
      {
        "type": "Available",
        "status": "False",
        "lastUpdateTime": "2020-08-20T13:34:52Z",
        "lastTransitionTime": "2020-08-20T13:34:52Z",
        "reason": "MinimumReplicasUnavailable",
        "message": "Deployment does not have minimum availability."
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

when the pod start, the log output like this:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to get driver instance for jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://45.131.218.134:3309/report?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&transformedBitIsBoolean=true&useSSL=false&verifyServerCertificate=false
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.<init>(DriverDataSource.java:110) ~[HikariCP-3.1.0.jar:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.initializeDataSource(PoolBase.java:334) ~[HikariCP-3.1.0.jar:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.<init>(PoolBase.java:109) ~[HikariCP-3.1.0.jar:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:108) ~[HikariCP-3.1.0.jar:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:81) ~[HikariCP-3.1.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.skywalking.oap.server.library.client.jdbc.hikaricp.JDBCHikariCPClient.connect(JDBCHikariCPClient.java:44) ~[library-client-6.5.0.jar:6.5.0]
    at org.apache.skywalking.oap.server.storage.plugin.jdbc.mysql.MySQLStorageProvider.start(MySQLStorageProvider.java:123) ~[storage-jdbc-hikaricp-plugin-6.5.0.jar:6.5.0]
    at org.apache.skywalking.oap.server.library.module.BootstrapFlow.start(BootstrapFlow.java:61) ~[library-module-6.5.0.jar:6.5.0]
    at org.apache.skywalking.oap.server.library.module.ModuleManager.init(ModuleManager.java:67) ~[library-module-6.5.0.jar:6.5.0]
    at org.apache.skywalking.oap.server.starter.OAPServerStartUp.main(OAPServerStartUp.java:43) [server-starter-6.5.0.jar:6.5.0]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.<init>(DriverDataSource.java:103) ~[HikariCP-3.1.0.jar:?]
    ... 9 more
```

I read the skywalking official issue and tell me because the mysql jdbc was GPL licence and SkyWalking is Apache license,so I must add the jdbc driver by myself, but how to add the jdbc driver jar into the image file? I have no ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how to add the jdbc driver jar into the image file?

One way would be an `initContainer:` and then artificially inject the jdbc driver via [`-Xbootclasspath`](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/mlvm/BootClassPath)

```yaml
initContainers:
- name: download
  image: busybox:latest
  command:
  - wget
  - -O
  - /foo/jdbc.jar
  - https://whatever-the-jdbc-url-jar-is-goes-here
  volumeMounts:
  - name: tmp
    mountPath: /foo
containers:
- env:
  - name: JAVA_OPTS
    value: -Xmx2g -Xbootclasspath/a:/foo/jdbc.jar
  volumeMounts:
  - name: tmp
    mountPath: /foo
volumes:
- name: tmp
  emptyDir: {}
```

a similar, although slightly riskier way, is to find a path that is already on the classpath of the image, and attempt to volume mount the jar path into that directory

All of this seems kind of moot given that your image looks like one that is custom built, and therefore the correct action is to update the `Dockerfile` for it to download the jar at build time